# Get Primary key of an element(Teacher) which is referred in student model django

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to Django and I don't know how to get access the primary key. I have a scenerio in which there are two users teacher and student one-to-one relationship to abstract user.In my case teachers create student accounts, I have created teachers accounts successfully,I also want to save students registered by the teachers which also know how to do it,but my problems is I also want to save the teacher in student model who registered that particular student, for this I want to get that teacher object(The teacher which is adding student at that time) which I can't,can someone provide suggestions or code how to do it?

Models.py File:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student=models.BooleanField(default="False")
    is_prof=models.BooleanField(default="False")


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    designation=models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Student(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher=models.ForeignKey(Teacher,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="")
    batch=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Below my piece of approach to add student, user is created successfully but what to do in last line student= so I can teacher object through teacher_id:

```
obj=User.objects.create_user(
    username=myids[iterate],password=passwords[iterate],
    is_student=True,is_prof=False)
obj.save()
Student.objects.create(user=obj,teacher=(What to do?),batch="F-14")
```

Comment: You get the `Teacher` object of a `Student` with `some_student.teacher`, or the `id` with `some_student.teacher_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `field` that is a `ForeignKey`, Django automatically creates a "twin field" named `field_id`, that stores the `id`. Updates to the `some_object.field` reflect in the `some_object.field_id`, and vice versa.

You can thus use the `teacher_id` field instead here:

```
obj= User.objects.create_user(
    username=myids[iterate],
    password=passwords[iterate],
    is_student=True,
    is_prof=False
)
obj.save()
Student.objects.create(user=obj, teacher_id=myteacherid, batch="F-14")
```

An alternative is to *first* fetch the `Teacher` object with the given `id`, and then use this, but this is *less* efficient, since it will result in *two* queries to construct the object: one to fetch the `Teacher`, and one to create the `Student`:

```
obj= User.objects.create_user(
    username=myids[iterate],
    password=passwords[iterate],
    is_student=True,
    is_prof=False
)
obj.save()

my_teacher = Teacher.objects.get(pk=myteacherid)
Student.objects.create(user=obj, teacher=myteacher, batch="F-14")
```

Comment: Well I assume you have some sort of view where you encoded the teacher pk?

Comment: How exactly is this view called? How does a *user* calls this view?

Comment: View is called by this, url(r'^addfile/$',views.Addfile.as_view(),name='file')

Comment: @MUHAMMADNABEELL1F14BSCS0108: this doesn't seem to make much sense, since this looks like you *add a file*. Furthermore the URL has no teacher parameter, so then the parameter should be in the `request.GET` or `request.POST`, but this is typically then handled by the form. Can you update the question with the (relevant) views and forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the teacher object and assign it to 'teacher' field in Student model.

teacher = get_object_or_404(Teacher, pk=*primary_key_of_teacher*)

student = Student(user=*user_object* teacher=**teacher** batch=*student_batch*)

student.save()